# Grails : Adding text color to g:formatDate

Tags: grails

I am working on an app in Grails 2.3.6

I want to add text color to the Date object in GSP view. I tried the following and this didn't work.

```
<td><g:formatDate date="${myClassInstance.lastName}" style="color: green;"/></td>
```

Is there a way to add color to g:formatDate?

Comment: What Josh says below... plus, probably, change "lastName" to something that might have a Date in it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your class on the surrounding element such as the `td` or add a `<span></span>` around your date. `g:formatdate` does not return HTML but rather just text.

```
<td style="color: green;"><g:formatDate date="${myClassInstance.lastName}"/></td>
```

or

```
<td><span style="color: green;"><g:formatDate date="${myClassInstance.lastName}"/></span></td>
```